# Dash App is not loading GeoJSON Object as Source

Tags: python

I am working on a Dash app modeled after a sample app found here(https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/dash-opioid-epidemic/). The app featured provides a link to a GeoJSON file read from GitHub user content to construct a layer for the map.

```
    base_url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jackparmer/mapbox-counties/master/"
for bin in BINS:
    geo_layer = dict(
        sourcetype="geojson",
        source=base_url + str(year) + "/" + bin + ".geojson", <-- HERE
        type="fill",
        color=cm[bin],
        opacity=DEFAULT_OPACITY,
        # CHANGE THIS
        fill=dict(outlinecolor="#afafaf"),
    )
    layout["mapbox"]["layers"].append(geo_layer)
```

For my use, I want to dynamically construct a GeoJSON object from a geopandas dataframe. I have achieved this and construct a feature collection as a GeoJSON object - see example below. When I check the type of the object it is this "geojson.feature.FeatureCollection".

```
{"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": [[-74.734949, 39.727779], [-74.417286, 39.557994], [-74.313224, 39.497748], [-74.548733, 39.295101], [-74.860918, 39.322485], [-74.986888, 39.514178], [-74.877349, 39.607286], [-74.734949, 39.727779]], "geometry": [[-74.734949, 39.727779], [-74.417286, 39.557994], [-74.313224, 39.497748], [-74.548733, 39.295101], [-74.860918, 39.322485], [-74.986888, 39.514178], [-74.877349, 39.607286], [-74.734949, 39.727779]], "type": "Polygon"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}], "type": "FeatureCollection"}
```

According to the documentation, a GeoJSON object may be passed as the source. Therefore, I do it in the following way.

```
        geo_df = (df_cur[(df_cur['val_bins'] == str(bin))]).copy() # geo
    geo_json=make_geo_json(geo_df)
    geo_layer = dict(
        sourcetype="geojson",
        source=geo_json,
        type="fill",
        color=cm[bin],
        opacity=DEFAULT_OPACITY,
        # CHANGE THIS
        fill=dict(outlinecolor="#afafaf"),
    )
```

Despite constructing it and it being of the correct type, it is not displaying.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After much debugging and comparison using the original source code, I found that the issue was in the coordinates of the polygons. If you visit the below code section, you will see two arrows around the coordinates. These denote the issue spot. I resolved this by simply adding the array which I created to another array. Thus achieving "coordinates": --->[[[-74.734949, 39.727779], ... [-74.548733, 39.295101]]] - which is properly nested.

```
{"features": [{"geometry": {"coordinates": --->[[-74.734949, 39.727779], [-74.417286, 39.557994], [-74.313224, 39.497748], [-74.548733, 39.295101], [-74.860918, 39.322485], [-74.986888, 39.514178], [-74.877349, 39.607286], [-74.734949, 39.727779]], "geometry": [[-74.734949, 39.727779], [-74.417286, 39.557994], [-74.313224, 39.497748], [-74.548733, 39.295101], [-74.860918, 39.322485], [-74.986888, 39.514178], [-74.877349, 39.607286], [-74.734949, 39.727779]]<---, "type": "Polygon"}, "properties": {}, "type": "Feature"}], "type": "FeatureCollection"}
```